# Getting list of all iPhone apps available in AppStore [ie details of 3,500,000 apps now]

Tags: iphone, app-store, itunes-store

How can I get a list of all iPhone apps available in the app store (i.e. about 3,500,000 apps to date)? I need to get list of all apps. At least the name would do, because if I get name I can find out details using the iTunes search API.

Why do I need it? I need to do some data mining and some cool stuff with that data.

The iTunes search API won't allow me to fetch this much data, right? That makes sense, Apple can't afford spend their bandwidth to give out details on 3,500,000 apps at a time for a single developer.

Comment: LMGTFY: http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html